# Regex for capturing group ordering with comma separation

Tags: java, regex

I need regex which matches a URL pattern which takes arguments in any order with comma separation.
e.g The regex should match:

```
/abcd(id1='some_value',id2='some_value')
```

as well as

```
/abcd(id2='some_value',id1='some_value',id2='some_value')
```

There can't be any additional arguments in the URL. Each argument should match exactly once.

The following regex matches all arguments in any order but without a comma between them. How do I add add a comma between the arguments in regex?

```
\/abcd\((?:id='.*'()|name='.*'()|count='.*'()){3}\1\2\3\)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each argument should match exactly once.

is the major concern.

For your example i came up with the following regex:

```regex
/abcd\s*\((?!(?:'[^']*'|[^')])*(?<=[\s(,])(name|count|id)(?=[\s=])(?:'[^']*'|[^')])*(?<=[\s,])\1(?=[\s=]))(?:(?<=[(,])\s*(?:name\s*=\s*'(?<name>[^']*?)'|count\s*=\s*'(?<count>[^']*?)'|id\s*=\s*'(?<id>[^']*?)')\s*[,)]){3}(?<=\))
```

Its quite long so lets break it down.

```regex
/<function name>\s*\(...(?<=\))
```

Matches the function name `function name`, the opening `(` (+ assert that the regex ends with a closing `)`), optional space (which i won't discuss for the rest of the regex) and a `/` before the name. Note that java does not need to escape the `/`.

```regex
(?!...)
```

This is the part that checks that no argument is used multiple times.
The `...` gets replaced by a subregex that will match if the same value is used twice. The subregex is a broken down form of the complete regex, to imitate matching name-value pairs.

```regex
(?:'[^']*'|[^')])*
```

Match (as many as possible) any character that is neither `'` nor a closing `)` alternatively match a *value*, which is delimited by `'` and does not contain `'`. This will effectively read whitespace, commas, equality signs and argnames and **complete** values.

```regex
(?<=[\s(,])(<argname1>|<argname2>|...)(?=[\s=])
```

Match any of the argument names `argname<n>`. Also check that it's a complete name and not just a substring. It's a complete name if there is either whitespace a comma or an opening `(` before the name. After a complete name is either whitespace or a `=`. The matched argname is stored in capture group 1. Note that this subregex (inside the `(?!...)`) is written in a way that it matches **any** name. So it will try to match all argnames and accepts only if no (no = not any) argname is used twice.

```regex
(?:'[^']*'|[^')])*
```

Same as above. Match every charecter or complete values.

```regex
(?<=[\s,])\1(?=[\s=])
```

Rematch the content of the first capture group (any argname) as a complete name (space or comma before name, space or `=` after name).
This is the important part.
**This** is the test for the second use of the argument name.

```regex
(?:(?<=[(,])\s*(?:...)\s*[,)]){<num arguments>}
```

Matches `num arguments` many arguments. Each argument must start with a opening `(` (the first one) or a comma (everything but the first). Also each argument must end with a comma or closing `)`.

The `...` contains the argument specification and the capturing groups in the form

```regex
<argname1>\s*=\s*'(?<argname1>[^']*)'|<argname2>\s*=\s*'(?<argname2>[^']*)'|...
```

Where the value for `agname<n>` is stored in a capture group with the same name. You can get that value from the java `Matcher` by using the argname as groupname. Take for example `matcher.group("count")`.

See an [example](https://regex101.com/r/URBZuz/1).

Comment: Just one concern here, it takes any number of commas at the end of the arguments.
Will take some time to understand the regex you provided to make the modification to this as I am quite new to regex.

Comment: @SaurabhJain I don't understand what you mean. The regex ensures there is exactly one comma between each argument but not before the first and not after the last. Do you have an example where it fails?

Comment: My Bad. Works perfect for my use case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Well, i did some slight modifications. If it works would you consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Found one case where it fails. The regex matches the following string:
/abcd(name='{bar}', id='{foo}', count='{foo2}',
i.e. ending with comma instead of ')'

Comment: @SaurabhJain As i said, i updated my answer and made some slight modifications. Please recheck with the [modified version](https://regex101.com/r/7VmkB5/1)

Comment: Yes, this one works perfectly. Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: Found one more case. If the name of one argument is a substring in the name of another argument, the regex doesn't match.
For e.g. one argument being id and another argument xid or idx or xidx.
This is very weird behaviour.

Comment: @SaurabhJain I will work on that. Can i assume that there are no spaces in the name?

Comment: Yes, no spaces in the name.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Do you allow escaping `'` inside the values? This would make it more complicated but should be possible.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Please try `/abcd\s*\((?!(?:'[^']*+'|[^')])*(?<=[\s(,])(id|idx|xidx)(?=[\s=])(?:'[^']*+'|[^')])*(?<=[\s,])\1(?=[\s=]))(?:(?<=[(,])\s*(?:id\s*=\s*'(?<id>.*?)'|idx\s*=\s*'(?<idx>.*?)'|xidx\s*=\s*'(?<xidx>.*?)')\s*[,)]){3}(?<=\))`. If it works for you i will modify my answer and add a description.

Comment: This seems to be working fine for the scenarios mentioned previously.
One concern for the above regex you mentioned in the last comment: if I add an additional parameter to the path, the regex still validates it to true. e.g. `/abcd(idx='bar', id='foo2', xidx='foo', new='bar2')`. Though the regex doesn't have 'new' as key, the url is matched, as it considers "foo', new='bar2" as the value of key xidx, which clearly is not the case.

Comment: @SaurabhJain As the regex is right now, it allows for unescaped `'` in the value (between two `'`). But this will lead to the result that you mentioned. If this is not the behaviour you want then we have the option to 1) Don't allow `'` inside the value 2) allow `'` in the value only if escaped.

Comment: Yes, option 1 would work. Not allowing `'` inside the value. If possible please update the regex with that. I will accept the answer for now and also perform a thorough checking once tomorrow. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Here's the regex:
`/abcd\s*\((?!(?:'[^']*+'|[^')])*(?<=[\s(,])(name|count|count2)(?=[\s=])(?:'[^']*+'|[^')])*(?<=[\s,])\1(?=[\s=]))(?:(?<=[(,])\s*(?:name\s*=\s*'(?<name>.[^']*?)'|count\s*=\s*'(?<count>.[^']*?)'|count2\s*=\s*'(?<count2>.[^']*?)')\s*[,)]){3}(?<=\))`

Comment: @SaurabhJain The only thing that you got wrong is the colon (`.`) in the named capture groups. Remove those and it should work. Updated regex end description in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the options with commas between them, you can change the `()` for `,` after the value for the id's, and add an extra clause for the ending argument

This regex (sightly different from yours) would match any amount of arguments between the parenthesis, separated by comma and space

`\/abcd\((id='[^']*', |name='[^']*', |count='[^']*', )*(id='[^']*'|name='[^']*'|count='[^']*')\)`

Here you can try it out [regexr.com/4iqlu](https://regexr.com/4iqlu)

EDIT: Replaced .* for [^']*, since we want to make sure that the regex doesnt capture outside the ''